Twisting irreversible Lock Mechanism
I need to create a design of two part. One has thread in external diameter, other one has thread in inner diameter. Both of the part will be made in plastic material. Once mated two parts, they can't be detachable. So, the lock has to be made that way.
Can anyone give me any idea how to do so?

So many solutions exist if you look a bit. tags fitting into slots etc

Sounds like you just need a snap hook at the end of the thread travel
